# Get MAC-address from windows registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry

i have registry from another machine and i need to extract mac-address from ethernet adapter

the adapter settings in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\old_registry\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0009`

and there is parameter:

`BIMacAdddress_l (REG_DWORD) = f315d433`  and it is hexadecimal, decimal is `4078294067`

when in submenu choose "Edit binary data" i see something like this:

0000    33 D4 15 F3      (and here is two some weird symbols)

33 D4 15 F3 looks like MAC address which is i looking for, but its only 8-characters, normal mac has 12 characters.

screenshot with registry tree:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/m8ssP.png]

So what i doing wrong?

Comment: 0000 33 D4 15 F3 means that you are starting at address 0000 and have four bytes in little endian order (reversed). hence you have the data f315d433.

Comment: And how exactly did `BIMacAdddress_h` and `BIMacAdddress_l` come into existence? I did some research. It turns out these are named symbols in a PE called `l160x64.sys` which is a driver for Atheros L1 Gigabit Ethernet adapter. I am not surprised. This is exactly what we see in the screenshot.

Comment: You will normally not find the MAC address in the Windows registry. Not unless an administrator overrides the UAA address with an LAA address, in which case you will find a `NetworkAddress` field in one of the sub-keys of class key `{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}`. What you have found is a hardly readable MAC address, which most likely has been registered by the NIC driver, unless you were doing some funny business and put it in there yourself.

Comment: By the way, "BI" as in `BIMacAdddress_h` stands for binary. It's meant to be readable by the operating system and possibly the NIC driver, not by humans. It's no wonder it's incomprehensible.

Answer (score 5):

I would assume that the MAC address is 00:18:f3:15:d4:33 (belongs to "Asustek" which is a mainboard manufacturer).

The trick is that the MAC address has 48bit and is saved splitted into a high (BIMacAddress_h) and a low (BIMacAddress_l) part. Therefore you have to combine both parts and then use the lower 48bits of the resulting 64bit number. Then you get the MAC address above.

Comment: I can confirm your assumtion is 100% correct.

Comment: if this is true, why I'm reading "Atheros" in the DriverDesc and ProviderName (in the screenshot) ? which is a network device manufacturer

Comment: I a mainboard manufacturer like Asustek buys network chips for their mainboards they often change the MAC address to one of their own pool. Therefore I don'T see a problem in having an Atheros LAN chip with an Asustek MAC address.

Answer (score -1):

Hey the four zeroes are also considered as the mac address and therefore its a valid mac - 000033D415F3 .

Comment: This answer is not correct.  You need to combine BIMacAddress_h and BIMacAddress_l in order to get the correct MAC address.  BIMacAddress_l is equal to `f315d433` thus `33:d4:14:f3` is the second half of the address.  The first part is 0000`0018` which is 00:18 combine them and you have the correct address.